# как скрыть или убрать фон в html тэге

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="special-offer special-offer_pad30px"style="background-image:url('image/offer/special_offer/bg-special-offer.jpg')" >


@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
    .special-offer_pad30px {
        background-image: none;
    }
}
```

Не работает в медиа запросах

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы "перебить" стили, прописанные инлайн (прямо в теге), Вы должны добавить в медиа-запросе !important. Но лучше не писать стили в тегах - это плохая практика.

```css
.special-offer_pad30px {
  height: 400px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
    .special-offer_pad30px {
        background-image: none !important;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="special-offer special-offer_pad30px" style="background-image:url('https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/1025945/a90fea59-ab59-463a-8f9e-eeb926b41e00/s1200')">
```